# Cannot apply the positional operator without a corresponding query field containing an array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have following document:

```
{ "id" : "1",
"name": "Paul",
"a": { "b" : [{"name" : "laura", "lastname" : "Palmer"}]}
}
```

Now I want to update every lastname in b.

I tried this:

```
    db.organizations.update({"name" : "Paul", "a.b" : {$exists: true}},
{ "$set" : {"a.b.$.lastname" : "no_lastname"}});
```

But I get:
Cannot apply the positional operator without a corresponding query field containing an array.

Anybody has an idea what I should do?

Comment: Its been discussed many many times in stack-overflow, you just can update one item with $ op, you cant update all array's entries

Comment: How should I do it then?

Comment: Conceptually the error you get is because the `query` parameter must contain the field that you are using with the positional operator `$` in the `projection` parameter. If your query contains `"a.b.lastname":{$exists:true}`, you would not get this error, but anyway only the first sub document in `b` that matches the query would get updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of the [`cursor.forEach()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.forEach/) cursor method in the mongo shell to achieve this:

```js
db.organizations.find({"name" : "Paul", "a.b" : {$exists: true}}).forEach(function(doc) {
    array = doc.a.b; 
    array.forEach(function(elem) {
        elem.lastname="no_lastname"
    }); 
    db.organizations.update({_id:doc._id}, {$set:{"a.b":array}}); 
})
```

Comment: Isn't there a way to do it in 1 statement?

Comment: Nope, there isn't.. as yet.